# Making a site bilingual

Tags: html, css, web

Apologies in advance if this is a simple question -- I'm very new to web development.

I'm trying to make a site multi-lingual (EN & FR).

I understand how to get the buttons to switch from an English site to a French site and vice versa.

HTML:

```html
<body>
 <a href="#eng" data-reload>English</a>
 <a href="#fr" data-reload>Français</a>

 
 <script>
 //define language reload anchors
  var dataReload = document.querySelectorAll("{data-reload]");


 //Language Translations
  var language = {
   eng:{
    Hello: "Hi!"
   },
   
   fr:{
    Hello: "Bonjour!"
   }
  };
  //Define language via window hash
  if (window.location.hash){
   if (window.location.hash === "#fr") {
    hi.textContent = language.fr.hello;
   }
  }
 
 //Define language reload onclick illiteration
 for(i=0;i<=dataReload.length;i++){
  dataReload[i].onclick=function(){
   location.reload(true);
   };
  }
 </script>
```

The entire site is in English. But I'm not sure how to actually translate the French page... there's very little words so I don't mind translating it myself. ***Is there any way to do this?***

(I've heard great things about i18n, but don't fully understand how to use it yet.)

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by how to translate the French page? You can have a human like yourself translate it, or you can use an automated translation tool like Google Translate or DeepL. Is that what you’re asking?

Comment: What framework is doing most of the rendering? Is there a server-side framework involved or is it all js? Is it vanilla js or is there a js framework?

Comment: I assume you've seen Google's translate button: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_google_translate.asp

Comment: Considering your code snippet in the question, you can approach this using Objects in JavaScript. https://jsfiddle.net/j8shc0mk/

Comment: Hi all, here's some clarification:
What do I mean by how to translate the page - I mean that I want to translate it myself (without Google translate), but don't know how to go about it. When I click "French", I still see everything in English. How do I make it so I see my writing in French?

What framework is doing the rendering - It's all just plain, old js. No server-side framework or other js framework

Google translate - I've seen and tried it, but it makes my load time way too long

Answer (score 1):

My experience is in Java (Spring specifically). I'm guessing that may not be what you are using, but perhaps the basic concepts will apply to other frameworks:

The way Spring works is you define a bunch of language (locale)-specific message files with all of your translated messages. These files are named by locale. So, for french you might have a file called `messages_fr.properties` with the following:

```
greeting=Bonjour! Bienvenue sur notre site!
lang.change=Changez la langue
lang.eng=Anglais
lang.fr=Francais
```

The above defines a bunch of language specific key-values. Different language files will have different values but the same keys. Then in your html template, you use the key as such:

```
<h1><spring:message code="greeting" text="default"/></h1>
```

Spring then looks up the `greeting` key based on whatever that user's locale is set to. If it's set to french, it will look in the abovementioned french file with the result `Bonjour! Bienvenue sur notre site!`. If it's set to english, it will look in the english file.

Obviously, other frameworks may do things differently, but maybe that overview will be useful in some way. More info on the Spring way can be found here:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-internationalization

If you are trying to roll your simple internationalization framework (which idk might not be the best plan depending on how much it's used), you could probably have a similar setup with a global locale setting tied to the user and a message lookup mechanism where text is looked up based on a language agnostic key + the user's locale setting. This lookup could be just a lookup in a global js object, or something server-side, depending on where your templating is. Then your template code would only reference the lookup function and the key, and not have to worry about hardcoded language values. And your links to change the site language would only have to change the locale setting for that user, probably stored in their session or some equivalent.